# Application of Ito's Lemma to a process

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is a function $S(X)=(A+1/b X_t)^b$, where $A$ and $b$ are constant

I'll need to show how to get $dS = \frac13 S^{1/3} dX^2 + S^{2/3} dX$ and determine the value of $b$

Answer (score 0):

Ito's Lemma gives you the following.
$$dS(t) = S_x(X(t))dX(t) + \frac{1}{2}S_{xx}(X(t))dX(t)dX(t)$$ where $S_x$ denotes the partial derivative of $S$ with respect to $X$.

Substituting $$S_x(X(t)) = \left( A + \frac{1}{b}X(t)\right)^{b-1} = S(X(t))^{\frac{b-1}{b}}$$
and $$S_{xx}(X(t)) = \frac{b-1}{b}\left( A + \frac{1}{b}X(t)\right)^{b-2} = \frac{b-1}{b}S(X(t))^{\frac{b-2}{b}}$$
and equating the $dX(t)$ term to that in the expression for $dS$ given in your question, you can see that $b = 3$.